# Avoid "wc_add_to_cart_params is not defined" error in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add products to the cart in woocommerce, but am getting a persistent error `Uncaught ReferenceError: wc_add_to_cart_params is not defined`.

Have used this approach many times before without issue, has wc_add_to_cart_params been removed from woocommerce? If so what is the replacement?

My code is as follows:

```
  var productId = form.find('input[name=product_id]').val();
  var variationId = form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val();
  var qty = form.find('input[name=qty]').val();

  // Data array
  var data = {
    action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
    product_id: productId,
    variation_id: variationId,
    quantity: qty,
  };

  // Ajax function
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
    data: data,
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case this comes up for anyone else, it appears the `add-to-cart.min.js` only loads if 'Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives' is enabled in the WC settings. This resolves the issue for me.

Comment: 'Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives' worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct but the point is from where it is called. If it is a external js file then enqueue it in footer.

Comment: This makes sense, but what does it need to be called after? I'm not able to identify what script it is relying on?

Comment: I seem to have isolated the issue to the woocommerce script add-to-cart.min.js not loading. This is the file that seems to contain wc_add_to_cart_params. I've re-installed WC but with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: woocommerce does not load add-to-cart.min.js in all page of a site. It only appears on those page where the add to cart button is presented. If you want to handle it anywhere else you have to enqueue it manually for that page. Thank you.